# Can I still play Minecraft Xbox One edition if I've downloaded Better Together?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm in a bit of an annoying situation here. I got an Xbox one s for xmas and it came with a digital copy of Minecraft. I downloaded it but the better together version downloaded so now I'm stuck with this really bad version of Minecraft.

If I went and bought the disc version of Xbox one Minecraft edition, would it still work and be the old version?

Answer (score 1):

Owning the disc of the Xbox one edition should work. I own both versions. I am currently playing on the Xbox one edition. Aka the better one.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are two separate games, you can copy your old worlds from the Legacy Console version to the Bedrock Edition, but NOT from the Bedrock edition to the Legacy Console version...